# Getting HTML form elements to be in line

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using some bootstrap elements along with some buttons and have issues getting them all to show up in one line! I have something like:

```
<span><input class="form-control" id="filename" value="Select a ZIP file to upload..." disabled style="display: inline" ></span>
<span><input type="button" id="get_file" class="btn btn-primary" value="Browse" style="display: inline"></span>
<span><input type="button" id="get_file" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload" style="display: inline"></span>
<input type="file" id="my_file" accept=".zip" style="display: none">
```

This should basically show a text field with two buttons and I get an output like:

[image]

What i would like is for the two buttons to be on the same row as well...

Comment: refer to this: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: more specifically this section http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons-multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look to the Bootstrap Documentation :
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button>
    </span>
  </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Works great!

Comment: @Luca No problems :-) Don't forget to check this answer if it helped you!

Comment: Waiting for the stipulated time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<form class="form-horizontal form-inline">
        <span><input class="form-control" id="filename" value="Select a ZIP file to upload..." disabled ></span>
        <span><input type="button" id="get_file" class="btn btn-primary" value="Browse"></span>
        <span><input type="button" id="get_file" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload"></span>
        <input type="file" id="my_file" accept=".zip" style="display: none" >
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form class="form-inline">
<span><input class="form-control" id="filename" value="Select a ZIP file to upload..." disabled></span>
<span><input type="button" id="get_file" class="btn btn-primary" value="Browse"></span>
<span><input type="button" id="get_file2" class="btn btn-success" value="Upload"></span>
<input type="file" id="my_file" accept=".zip" style="display: none">
```

try it.

check this [document](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#inline-forms).